# How to connect a search field in a website with a textview

Tags: android

i want to know the below things are possible in android.

First: How can i connect with a search field in a website with a textview in my application.

Second: How can i display a pdf viewer from another website, i mean the pdfviwer with out any thing else in the website. I am tried with webview but i don't know what to do to only display the pdfviwer.

I saw something like that in this link but i didnt recognized what to do http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.htm

Comment: What do you call "connecting a TextView to a search field"?

Comment: what u mean by  this

Comment: hey did you find the solution..??